# Validation in input is working but add button event is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

html:

```html
<lightning-input name="number" 
                 class="validate" type="number"  label="firstNumber" 
                 onchange={numberChangeHandler}  
                 required="true" 
                 min="-9999999"
                 max="999999" 
                 message-when-range-overflow="Please enter a correct number" 
                 message-when-range-underflow="Please enter a correct number">
</lightning-input>
```

JS:-

```javascript
numberChangeHandler(event){
    const inputBoxName = event.target.number;
    if(inputBoxName === 'firstNumber'){
        this.firstNumber = event.target.value;
    } else if(inputBoxName === 'secondNumber'){
        this.secondNumber = event.target.value;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384014/edit) your question to add *how* it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text, *exact* unexpected results). *(Please read the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center where, among other things, it says that your question should include, 'A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help).')*

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `event.target.number` to `event.target.label`, then you will be able to get `firstNumber`.

Below code should work.

```javascript
numberChangeHandler(event){
    const inputBoxName = event.target.label;
    if(inputBoxName === 'firstNumber'){
       this.firstNumber = event.target.value;
    } else if(inputBoxName === 'secondNumber'){
       this.secondNumber = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Here is the lighting-input documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation

Comment: yes its working thankyou..

Comment: @vaibhav Please mark this as best answer that will help other developers as well.